# How to sort through keys in a dictionary, adding the values and returning a list of keys if combined values equal a certain number

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of keys that have different integer values, e.g.

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':12, 'c':33, 'd':40, 'e':15, 'f':6, 'g':27}
```

I want to be able to return a list of keys whose combined values equal a certain number, e.g.

```
number = 55
result = ['d', 'e']
```

I'm not sure how to approach the problem, or whether I should be thinking about it iteratively or recursively.  I'm at a bit of a loss on this one.
At the moment I am working in Python 2.7, but wouldn't mind seeing solutions in Python 3 as well.
To be honest, even suggestions would be appreciated at this stage.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the number of items isn't too large, you can brute-force this:

```
import itertools
def matches(d, target):
    # First try single items, then couples, then triplets etc.
    for num in range(1,len(d)+1):
        # Iterate over all possible combinations of length num
        for com in itertools.combinations(d.items(), num):
            # Does the sum of all second items per key/value pair match the target?
            if sum(item[1] for item in com) == target:
                # Yield one item at a time, so the caller can decide when to stop
                yield com
```

You can use it to iterate over all matches:

```
>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':12, 'c':33, 'd':40, 'e':15, 'f':6, 'g':27}
>>> for match in matches(mydict,55):
...     print(match)
...
(('d', 40), ('e', 15))
(('c', 33), ('e', 15), ('f', 6), ('a', 1))
(('b', 12), ('e', 15), ('g', 27), ('a', 1))
```

or add a `break` after the `print()` line to make your program stop at the first match.

Comment: I like what you did there.  It's more elegant than what I was expecting and I can kind of follow what's going on, even though I am unfamiliar with itertools and combinations.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ErmahgerdLulz: I added some comments; you should definitely check out the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). While you're at it, also read about [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) which is full of extremely useful objects.

Answer (score 0):

1)Sort dictionary to create a list of tuples .
 2)Now, For each index `i` in sorted list, find index `j` for which
   `sum-value_at_index_i` is equal to `value_at_index_j` .

```
a= {'a':1, 'b':12, 'c':33, 'd':40, 'e':15, 'f':6, 'g':27}
# Lets sort it first
a_sort = sorted(a.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])
n=len(a)
i=j=flag=0
sum=55 #Input the sum from user
result = []
while i<n:
        j=i+1
        while j<n:
                if (sum-a_sort[i][1]) == a_sort[j][1] :
                        result.append(a_sort[j][0])
                        result.append(a_sort[i][0])
                        flag=1
                        break
                else:
                        j=j+1
        if flag==1:
                break
        i=i+1

print result
```

Output:

```
['d', 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks.  You code works, but I'm having a little trouble understanding what's going on.  I'm relatively new to Python, so my next mission will be to understand your code.
Thanks again.